# Red light from headphone jack Macbook Pro

Tags: lubuntu, pulseaudio, mac, macbook, headphones

I'm using Lubuntu 17.10 fully updated almost clean install on a Macbook Pro Retina late 2013. Audio is working perfectly fine through both inbuilt speakers and headphones.
My headphone jack is sending a red light out constantly. I've tried disabling IEC958 through amixer and alsamixer. This does not disable the red light and once pulseaudio gets restarted it reverts to default (on). (It doesn't happen and never has on OSX).

> $ amixer
>
> Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
>
> > Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
> >
> > Playback channels: Mono
> >
> > Mono: Playback [off]
>
> Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
>
> > Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
> >
> > Playback channels: Mono
> >
> > Mono: Playback [off]
>
> Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
>
> > Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
> >
> > Playback channels: Mono
> >
> > Mono: Playback [off]
>
> Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
>
> > Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
> >
> > Playback channels: Mono
> >
> > Mono: Playback [off]
>
> Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
>
> > Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
> >
> > Playback channels: Mono
> >
> > Mono: Playback [off]

I also tried ylwghst's solution found at [Help me kill this red light coming from headphone jack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777640/help-me-kill-this-red-light-coming-from-headphone-jack) . This didn't solve the problem (might have something to do with my limited understanding of the config file - it did make my computer think the microphone was a speaker, and did disable all audio-capabilities).

If I go to pulsaudio and change config to analog surround it does fix the red light, however it also disable all sound-capabilities.

I also tried wutangforever's suggestion found on [ALSA Mixer settings won't save (Kubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719859/alsa-mixer-settings-wont-save-kubuntu/741769#741769) . This did disable the red light without interfering with sound settings, however once I start playing any sound the red light comes back. Once the sound is disabled for a couple of seconds it turns off. This is better, but would still prefer it completely disabled.

Comment: Did you try blowing air into the jack?  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3694502

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention I also tried to blow in it and take a minijack in and out of the slot a couple of times.

Comment: Did you try Zapping the PRAM?  Option+Command+P+R when you power on and let it zap it a few times.

Comment: Hmm... Haven't tried it, but I would assume I would get the red light in OSX if this was the problem. Same with blowing in the port and such. I guess no harm in trying though.

Comment: I'm just trying to think of all the things that I have done in the past when I was a Mac / Apple certified tech helping customers out with their issues.  For the life of me though, I cannot remember what caused the red light to turn on in the first place.

Comment: Try `amixer set IEC958 off`